# Find extra character between two strings

Tags: javascript, java, string, algorithm, binary-tree

How can I find an extra character between two strings in an optimal way.

```
Ex1: S1 - 'abcd', S2 - 'abcxd', output - 'x'
Ex2: S1 - '100001', S2 - '1000011', output - '1'
```

We can do this by traversing linearly and comparing each character in O(n). I want this to be done in much more optimal way, say in `O(logn)`

Comment: are you sure there is only 1 xtra character ?

Comment: Yes. Only 1 character. Need to find just that extra character.

Comment: Attack from both sides until one side is different. Or, you could have the two char arrays produce a new array with each character diff result (using `charCodeAt()`). The first non-zero is diff.

Comment: You could think of some divide and conquer approach. Check the middle of the strings. If this letter is different, you know that the additional character is either this letter or before this position. But if they are equal, you haven't gained anything. So the worst case is still linear. And I'm pretty sure you can't do better than this.

Comment: You could also combine those two approaches into a recursive algorithm: check the middle, as Nico suggested.  if different, then check(left), else check(right).  Where check() uses @Jecoms two-sided attack.

Comment: @SamHazleton, that's incorrect, as the strings 'abbba' and 'aabbba' will have you checking to the right of the middle character.

Comment: If any new character is inserted, all characters to the right move one index right. Start in the middle, if different, move left, if not check index +1 and move right. I think, this is the solution.... But need inputs.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex speaks the truth.

Answer (score 1):

Baseline method (O(n)): Just comparing chars and narrowing in on both sides each cycle.

```js
function findDiffChar(base, baseExtraChar) {  
  let extraLastIndex = base.length;
  let lastIndex = extraLastIndex - 1;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < extraLastIndex / 2; i++) {
    console.log(`Loop: ${i}`);
    
    if (base[i] !== baseExtraChar[i])      
      return baseExtraChar[i];
    
    if (base[lastIndex - i] !== baseExtraChar[extraLastIndex - i])
      return baseExtraChar[extraLastIndex - i];
        
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(findDiffChar('FOOOOOAR', 'FOOOOOBAR')); // B
```

Improved method using binary search (O(log n)): Compare halves until you've narrowed it down to one character.

```js
function findDiffChar(base, baseExtraChar) {
  if (baseExtraChar.length === 1) return baseExtraChar.charAt(0);
 
  let halfBaseLen = Number.parseInt(base.length / 2) || 1;
  let halfBase = base.substring(0,halfBaseLen);
  let halfBaseExtra = baseExtraChar.substring(0,halfBaseLen);

  return (halfBase !== halfBaseExtra) 
      ? findDiffChar(halfBase, halfBaseExtra)
      : findDiffChar(base.substring(halfBaseLen),baseExtraChar.substring(halfBaseLen));
}

console.log(findDiffChar('FOOOOAR', 'FOOOOBAR')); // B
console.log(findDiffChar('---------', '--------X')); // X
console.log(findDiffChar('-----------', '-----X-----')); // X
console.log(findDiffChar('------------', '---X--------')); // X
console.log(findDiffChar('----------', '-X--------')); // X
console.log(findDiffChar('----------', 'X---------')); // X
```

Comment: But this is still linear. O(n)

Comment: @user3422229 Updated with alternate recursive strategy.